# In Scala invoking no-parameter function with and without brackets is executed in different way

Tags: scala, currying

I have following Currying function declaration:

```
def logString(count: Int)(fun:() => Unit) {
  for (n <- 1 to count) { fun }
}
```

I call this function in this way:

```
logString(3) { () => print("I") }
```

The result is nothing - just no output.

Then I just add brackets after "fun" function invocation, inside the body of Currying function declaration:

```
def logString(count: Int)(fun:() => Unit) {
  for (n <- 1 to count) { fun() }
}
```

The result becomes what is expected:

**III**

***Is this some Scala bug, or there is some rule that I missed when learning Scala?***

I know that there is rule that when you declare function like this:
    def myFun = 1
we can not invoke it with brackets - the compilation fails.
*But having different results when invoking a function with and without brackets seems more like a bug.*

***Am I right or I miss something about Scala?***

Comment: I think `fun` is just a `val` in this case, it's like you'd write `val x = 10`, and then in a loop `for (n <- 1 to 5) { x }`

Comment: This was what occurred in my mind also when posted question. But seems to be not true. I did the following change:


    def logString(count: Int)(fun:() => Unit) {
          for (n <- 1 to count) { print(fun + "; ") }
      }

and the result is NOT something like:

    0; 0; 0;

but in console I have:

    <function0>; <function0>; <function0>;

Comment: Yes, exactly, because `fun` is a value definition, when you call `+` on it, then because it's of type `Function0` (and not a `String` for example) it is converted to string with a call to `toString` method. You get then `<function0>`, to which you append `;`. This happens 3 times.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting but it is first time I write here. So I just reformat my previous comment (after 5 mins it can not be edited).

This was what occurred in my mind also when posted question. But seems to be not true. I did the following change: 

`def logString(count: Int)(fun:() => Unit) { 
    for (n <- 1 to count) { print(fun + "; ") } 
}`

 and the result is NOT something like: 

`0; 0; 0; `

but in console I have: 
`<function0>; <function0>; <function0>; `

Comment: No problem about the formatting, but I believe, my comment holds true, isn't it? I will extend my answer to make it a bit more explicit.

Comment: @myQs - That's what you would expect if `fun` is a value - `fun + ";"` is evaluated as `fun.toString() + "; "` and `fun.toString` is `<function0>`. `fun` is not being evaluated in the print statement.

Comment: @Ipiepiora and @Lee Thanks for your replies, but are you really sure that `fun` is a `value definition`? I am asking because as far as I know in Scala each `val` at runtime has some value (for numeric types 0, etc) and when invoking toString() on it it prints that value. I think it is not possible some `val` even of type java.lang.Integer to exist in Scala runtime without assigned value to it. Even if we suppose in the JVM java.lang.Integer is `null`, it's method toString() would return `null`.
May be I will have to spend some time (when have it :) ) to see what is generated as Java code there

Comment: @myQs - yes, `fun` is a value of type `Function0` - functions are values in scala in the same way as `Int`s or `String`s are values. `toString` just returns a `String` representation of the value. For `Function0` instances this is `<function0>` - see the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/Function0.scala#L1).

Comment: @myQs actually they are not value definitions, but are just like value definitions in this case. Formally I think they are called value parameters checkout doc: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#function-declarations-and-definitions

Answer (score 8):

Look at the type of `fun`, it's `fun: () => Unit`. You can think of that as meaning that when you call it with `()`, you get `Unit` in return. Without explicitly calling it, `fun` refers to *the function as a value*, not the result of calling it. This is the essence of the concept of higher-order functions.

If it had type `fun: => Unit`, simply mentioning `fun` would cause it to be executed, in which case there would be no way to refer the function as a value.

Answer (score 5):

When you have such a declaration

```
val x = 10
```

this is a value definition. The value x can be an integer like in this case, 
but it can also be a function.

```
val y = () => println("i'm a function")
```

However either way, if you call it without parenthesis nothing will happen.

```
scala> val x = 10
x: Int = 10

scala> val y = () => println("i'm a function")
y: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> x
res0: Int = 10

scala> y
res1: () => Unit = <function0>
```

When you have a function definition like this:

```
def z() = println("i'm a function def")
```

Then you can omit parenthisis and call it without it.

```
scala> def z() = println("i'm a function def")
z: ()Unit

scala> z
i'm a function def
```

In your case `fun` is like a value definition (it's a [value parameter](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#function-declarations-and-definitions)).

What happens is that, when Scala evaluates your `for` expression it will just do nothing with `fun`.

Just the same as if you did `y` vs `y()` from the example above.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to share the information summarized by me based on the very helpful answers answers above and some additional research. Might be would be helpful for someone else also.
Functions can be declared in two ways in Scala:
 - **"call-by-name"** - they are represented in the byte code as normal Java functions in a straightforward way.
 - **"call-by-value"** - from Scala's abstract point of view they are stored in variables. Actually in the Byte code they are stored in classes implementing Single Abstract Method interfaces (SAM) and passed around as method parameters or as normal variables.

When we invoke a **"call-by-name"** function that does not take parameters it is always executed no matter how we call it with or without brackets.
So now *myFunction* and *myFunction()* is just the same.
When we invoke a **"call-by-value"** function that does not take parameters we have two cases:
 - when we do not have brackets after it - *myFunction* - we just refer to the variable pointing to the function without executing function itself.
 - when we have brackets - *myFunction()* - we actually call (execute) the function.

Different ways to declare function:

```
def myFunction = 5 * 5
```

This is **call-by-name** function. Declared this way no brackets allowed when calling it. So calling *myFunction()* will not compile. Call it this way: *myFunction*

```
def myFunction() = 5 * 5
```

This is **call-by-name** function. Can call the function with and without brackets - the effect is the same. So *myFunction* and *myFunction()* is just the same.

```
def myFunction = () => 5 * 5
```

This is **call-by-value** function (even when declared as ***def*** not ***val***) . When calling it with brackets - *myFunction()* - function is executed, when calling it without brackets - *myFunction* - function is NOT executed - just val holding it is being mentioned.

Similarly if we declare function as other function's parameter:

```
def enclosingFunc(myFunction: => Void)
```

This is **call-by-name** function. Inside enclosing function it will be executed only if called without brackets - *myFunction*. With brackets - *myFunction()* - will not compile.

In this case *enclosingFunc* could be called this way:

```
enclosingFunc(n = 1; n +=1)


def enclosingFunc(myFunction: () => Int)
```

This is **call-by-value** function. It matters how we invoke it in the body of enclosing function. If invoke it without brackets - *myFunction* - it will NOT be executed, but we just refer to the object holing it. If invoke it with brackets - *myFunction()* - it will be called and executed.

In this case *enclosingFunc* could be called only in this way:

```
enclosingFunc( () => n = 1; n +=1)
```

Comment: That touches on a lot of connected topics, but I would try not to overthink the essence of the point. `val` is evaluated upon declaration. `def` is evaluated upon usage in an evaluated expression. Function types with anything on the left side of the `=>` are evaluated when called with `(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the function `fun` doesn't isn't invoked, it juts sort of sits there.  Adding the parenthesis cause the passed-in function to be evaluated.